# SQL select: fits both id's

Tags: mysql, sql

Could you please help me with query to DB, i need to select products that have same combined ID's. 
For example products with ID's 70 and 75. They both have filters 1 and 12.

IN wont work, it will also take #66 cuz it has filter 1 there, but second one is 11 and thats not what i need....

```
  product_id | filter_id
  ______________________
  66         | 1
  66         | 11
  68         | 9
  69         | 13
  70         | 1
  70         | 12
  71         | 14
  72         | 4
  72         | 17
  73         | 7
  73         | 14
  74         | 16
  75         | 1
  75         | 12
```

Comment: Are you trying to get elements with filter 1 `AND` 12?

Comment: your problem is not clear enough. Can the filters be more than 2? Also, what is the expected result? Do you want along with filter id, or without...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM table AS t1
  JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
 WHERE t1.filter = 1
   AND t2.filter = 12
```

Comment: WORKED GREAT! Thank you for fast answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Product_ID
,       Filter_ID
FROM    Your_Table a
WHERE   Filter_ID = 1
   AND  EXISTS (
                 SELECT     NULL
                 FROM       Your_Table b
                 WHERE      Filter_ID = 12
                       AND  b.Product_ID = a.Product_ID
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want pairs that have exactly the same ids (and not specifically 1 and 12), then I would suggest using `group_concat()` to list the ids and then joining back to find the duplicates.  The following gets the list of filter lists that are duplicated, along with their list of products:

```
select filters, count(*) as numdups, group_concat(product_id) as products
from (select product_id, group_concat(filter_id order by filter_id) as filters
      from table t
      group by product_id
     ) pf
where count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by having:

```
SELECT
     product_id,
     COUNT(*) cnt
FROM
     tablename
WHERE
     filter_id IN (1,12)
GROUP BY
     product_id
     HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: Peraphs you add a DISTINCT in the COUNT